# How can I monkey-patch xarray to mimic its plotting functionality?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I'm trying to monkey patch xarray's DataArrays to come up with plotting methods that are similar but do something a little different. Since this is hard to explain, here's an example:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import xarray as xr

airtemps = xr.tutorial.open_dataset("air_temperature")
da = airtemps.air.isel(time=0)

da.plot() # plots something
da.plot.imshow() # plots something with imshow
```

I'm trying to introduce new methods that would work as

```py
da.pplot() # Would plot something
da.pplot.imshow() # Would plot with imshow
```

But I haven't been able to. Getting the first one to work is easy, but the second one is harder. Here's something I've tried

```py
def pplot(darray, **kwargs):
    print("Doing some things before plotting...")
    return darray.plot(**kwargs)
xr.DataArray.pplot = pplot

def imshow(darray, **kwargs):
    print("Doing some things before plotting with imshow...")
    return darray.plot.imshow(**kwargs)
xr.DataArray.pplot.imshow = imshow
```

But the second one is obviously not right:

```py
In [5]: da.pplot()
Doing some things before plotting...
Out[5]: <matplotlib.collections.QuadMesh at 0x7fb50deaf4f0>

In [6]: da.pplot.imshow()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-31cbeba401f8> in <module>
----> 1 da.pplot.imshow()

TypeError: imshow() missing 1 required positional argument: 'darray'
```

I've also tried using classes to do this (which I suspect is the correct way), but that also fails for me:

```py
class pplotBase(object):
    __all__ = []
    def __init__(self):
        return

    def __call__(self, **kwds):
        """
        """
        return self.plot(**kwds)

    def imshow(self, **kwds):
        print("imshowing")
        return self.plot.imshow(**kwds)
xr.DataArray.pplotBase = pplotBase
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is my latest attempt using classes based on the answer by @wjandrea.

If I create a `plot` instance I can do this:

```py
In [50]: plot = da.plot

In [51]: plot.__init__(plot._da) # This works and plots things normally
```

However, if I create a class to do something similar when it's initiated I get this:

```py
In [61]: import xarray as xr
    ...: class pplot(xr.DataArray.plot):
    ...: 
    ...:     def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    ...:         print("Doing things before plotting")
    ...:         print(dir(self))
    ...:         super().__init__(self._da, *args, **kwargs)
    ...:         pass
    ...: 
    ...:     @classmethod
    ...:     def imshow(*args, **kwargs):
    ...:         print("Doing things before imshowing")
    ...:         return super().imshow(*args, **kwargs)
    ...: xr.DataArray.pplot = pplot
    ...: 

In [62]: da.pplot()
Doing things before plotting
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_da', 'contour', 'contourf', 'hist', 'imshow', 'line', 'pcolormesh', 'step']
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-d64e208a974d> in <module>
----> 1 da.pplot()

<ipython-input-61-694113b8f0d2> in __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
      5         print("Doing things before plotting")
      6         print(dir(self))
----> 7         super().__init__(self._da, *args, **kwargs)
      8         pass
      9 

AttributeError: _da
```

To me this doesn't really make sense since I'm testing the attributes and methods of `self` inside the `__init__()` method and there's clearly a `_da` in there. So I have no idea why I can't access it!

I guess my confusion is: how can I access the `plot` instance of the `DataArray` used to create the class from the class's method?

Comment: This isn't so much an xarray question as a python one — we can replace the `DataArray` with a normal class and get the same question. Without answering it fully but hopefully enough for you to go from — `pplot` works because it's creating a method. `imshow` fails because it's a normal function in the first case, and `self` — a `pplotBase` instance doesn't have a `plot` method in the second.

Comment: @Maximilian, thanks for the comment. You're that that this doesn't have anything to do with xarray and matplotlib specifically, so I changed the tags (I don't know how to make a better title though)

Comment: @Maximilian Also thanks for pointing out the flaws. I kinda know the flaws already, but I honestly don't know how to circumvent them! For example, how to create a `plot` method in my class that isn't recursive...

Comment: @TomCho Since you removed the [tag:python-xarray] tag, could you edit the title to match? I just got confused and added back the tag before noticing the comments and undoing it.

Comment: @wjandrea thanks for the tip! Like I said, I agree that xarray shouldn't be in the title, but at the same time I can't think of a way to ask the question I wanna ask without mentioning xarray! (I'm lacking the words, either because I don't know enough Python or because English isn't my main language lol.) Feel free to change the title if you can think of a way though!

Comment: @TomCho Actually, after writing my answer, I'm thinking that this is actually specific to xarray because it does weird stuff to make `pplot` and `pplot.imshow` into methods.

Comment: @wjandrea Ah, I see. That's unfortunate. I appreciate the help anyway!

Answer (score 1):

A class is the correct way to do this, but you need to use inheritance, use `__init__` instead of `__call__`, and `imshow` needs to be an alternate constructor, i.e. `classmethod`.

I don't have `xarray`, but here's an example patching [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) that's similar:

```
import itertools

class cchain(itertools.chain):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Doing some things before chaining...')
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def from_iterable(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print('Doing some things before chaining iterable...')
        return super().from_iterable(*args, **kwargs)

itertools.cchain = cchain
```

```
>>> itertools.cchain()
Doing some things before chaining...
<__main__.cchain at 0x7f3793e88140>
>>> itertools.cchain.from_iterable([])
Doing some things before chaining iterable...
<__main__.cchain at 0x7f379341b700>
```

---

**Edit**: Actually, [`xarray.DataArray.plot()`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/d4b7a608bab0e7c140937b0b59ca45115d205145/xarray/plot/plot.py#L113) seems to be a function, not a class. I skimmed the code but it's going over my head, sorry. I'm not sure how they got [`xarray.DataArray.plot.imshow()`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/d4b7a608bab0e7c140937b0b59ca45115d205145/xarray/plot/plot.py#L850) to be a method.

**Edit 2**: Thanks to [@Maximilian](/users/3064736/maximilian) for pointing out that I was actually right the first time. I was confused because the library seems to be using [`class _PlotMethods`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/d4b7a608bab0e7c140937b0b59ca45115d205145/xarray/plot/plot.py#L432) as a [proxy for `plot`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/d4b7a608bab0e7c140937b0b59ca45115d205145/xarray/core/dataarray.py#L3053), which is pretty funky IMO, but if it ends up as a class in the end, this solution works out.

**Edit 3**: After testing with `xarray`, I confirmed that this in fact does not work. It seems to be due to the funky stuff I mentioned before. If someone can prove me wrong, I'm all ears.

Comment: You were right the first time! `xr.DataArray.plot` is a class, with an `imshow` method. It's a callable class, which is why `xr.DataArray.plot()` works

Comment: @Maximilian Oh! Huh, looks like they're using [`class _PlotMethods`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/d4b7a608bab0e7c140937b0b59ca45115d205145/xarray/plot/plot.py#L432) as a [proxy for `plot`](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/blob/d4b7a608bab0e7c140937b0b59ca45115d205145/xarray/core/dataarray.py#L3053). That's pretty funky IMO, but if it works out in the end, that's great :)

Comment: Thanks! This certainly helps, but I think the issue for me is different because I need to access the `DataArray` from inside the class. Even mimicking your example I wasn't able to do that. Please check out the update to my question if you can. Thanks!

Comment: @TomCho You forgot the `cls` parameter to `imshow()`. Apart from that, I'm not sure what's going on, but I'm taking a look.